# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe_Subscription::create() in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

```
Stripe_Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => $customer_id,
  "plan" => $plan_id,
  "trial_end" => $strtotime,
));
```

This code is not working for me, I have tried it in many ways. I have created customer and plan but I cannot add subscription for user.

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading library file, so you can use this link 
=>https://github.com/myg0v/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using an older version of Stripe's PHP library. The syntax you're using matches the syntax from the 1.x versions, but these versions never supported the `/v1/subscriptions` endpoint -- support this endpoint was added in version [3.13.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3130-2016-05-04).

I would recommend that you use the latest version (4.4.0) and upgrade your integration's code to use the newer syntax:

```
\Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => $customer_id,
  "plan" => $plan_id,
  "trial_end" => $strtotime,
));
```

Comment: I am using the latest library and having an issue Stripe_Subscription::create but when I call \Stripe\Subscription::create, I am getting an authentication error. Please note that same code works well for charge function.

Answer (score 0):

Check this full sample for reference

https://github.com/myg0v/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form